# Changing Text of Element Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, firefox

I am new to jQuery and am developing some practice code for FF using Netbeans 7.3 on Ubuntu 11.4.  I start out with the h1 element having the text "Hello world"  using the following html call.

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

I then try to change the test to "Good bye world", when I click on "Hello world" with the following jQuery code.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j( document ).ready( function() {
    $j("h1").click(function( event ) {   
        $("h1").html("Good bye world");
    });    
});
```

However, when I click on the h1 "Hello world" text, it stays "Hello world".  Is this the wrong code to change the text?

Comment: You mix `$` and `$j`. If you looked in your error console, you'd see an error message about it.

Comment: $("h1).html() does work btw. Correct the errors mentioned by Matt B.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes.  That was the problem.  $("h1").html("Good bye world");  should have been $j("h1").html("Good bye world");  Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {  
    $('h1').click(function() {  
        $(this).text('Goodbye, world');
    });
});
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jJkQw/).

As pointed out in the comments, you're mixing up your jQuery references too. Your code should be:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j( document ).ready( function() {
    $j("h1").click(function( event ) {   
        $j("h1").html("Good bye world");
    });    
});
```

Comment: Yes.  That was my problem.  I forgot to always put the j after $.  Thank you also for the demonstration on the use of this.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$(this).text('Goodbye, world');
```

if you want to append use

```
$(this).append('your text');
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried $j('h1').append('. I just clicked the right button'); for when I click the right button.  However, why would you use "this" instead of the element h1?  Would this not refer to the scope object?  Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a jquery reference here -

Correct Code should be -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j( document ).ready( function() {
            $j("h1").click(function( event ) {   
                $j("h1").html("Good bye world");
            });    
        });
</script>
```

In your code one line was - `$("h1").html("Good bye world");`

which should be -

```
$j("h1").html("Good bye world");
```